# How to avoid image preview 100kb of text while db update in angular 12 material UI image upload FormGroup object

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular12

I am using angular 12 with angular material for image upload with preview there is below formgroup object but i don't want to insert database with this 197kb of image preview text, i tried all possible option setValue/patchVale/delete but whenever i create new gallery  with file name only its automatically create that preview and i want to avoid this preview text while updating database.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could delete the `preview` property by using the `delete` statement before posting the data:

```
delete gallery[0].preview
```

Obviously you want to loop over the gallery to delete all preview properties.

See https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_property_object.asp